# Linq to sql query with Parent child relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I have following model for posting the question and replies to the question

**Model**

```
public partial class LMS_Question
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassDiscussionID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentClassDiscussionID { get; set; }
    public string Discussion { get; set; }
    public string DiscussionTitle { get; set; }
}
```

When user will post new question the '`ParentClassDiscussionID`' will be null and if any reply added to the question then '`ClassDiscussionID`' will be updated to '`ParentClassDiscussionID`'.

Basically ClassDiscussionID and ParentClassDiscussionID columns have parent-child relationship.

However, I want to show the data like DiscussionTitle,ReplyCount as follows

```
DiscussionTitle ReplyCount
-------------------------
Question1    2 Reponses
Question2    3 Reponses
Question3    5 Reponses
```

So, how can I achieve this using linq to sql query ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to change your model to something like this

```
public partial class LMS_ClassDiscussion
    {
        public LMS_ClassDiscussion()
        {
            LMS_ClassDiscussionchild = new List<LMS_ClassDiscussion>();
        }
        public int ClassDiscussionID { get; set; }
        public int? ParentClassDiscussionID { get; set; }
        public string Discussion { get; set; }
        public string DiscussionTitle { get; set; }
        public LMS_ClassDiscussion _LMS_ClassDiscussion { get; set; }
        public List<LMS_ClassDiscussion> LMS_ClassDiscussionchild { get; set; }
    }
```

then you need method to get all children of  parents

```
 public  List<LMS_ClassDiscussion> GetChildren(IList<LMS_ClassDiscussion> source, int? parentId)
        {
            var children = source.Where(x => x.ParentClassDiscussionID == parentId).ToList();
            //GetChildren is called recursively again for every child found
            //and this process repeats until no childs are found for given node, 
            //in which case an empty list is returned
            children.ForEach(x => x.LMS_ClassDiscussionchild = GetChildren(source, x._LMS_ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID));
            return children.ToList();

        }
```

call method this way

```
 var LMS_ClassDiscussions = GetChildren(query, null);
  foreach (var item in LMS_ClassDiscussions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item._LMS_ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID + "="+item.LMS_ClassDiscussionchild.Count);
        }
```